# Using Nested Iterators in ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, iterator

I have two polylines (say two paths/roads/etc. for example) that I want to iterate against another set of iterated polylines (ie. geologic fault lines).

I want the first iterator to take Path #1 and iterate against each "Fault Line" (the 2nd iterator).  Then iterate Path #2 against the "Fault Line" polylines.  How do I do this?  I tried but cannot get it to work.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE, can you go into more depth what you tried (steps, screen shots...etc)?

Comment: You need to read up on help or search forums about embedding models within models. A model can only have one iterator.

Comment: Another option to consider that will give you more control would be to use a python/arcpy cursor (http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002z0000001q000000).

Comment: i know they can only have one iterator however if you have it as a "tool" and you add that tool it should work...correct?

Comment: artwork21...I had created two independent paths and created an iterator for those named "path iterator".  then i imported some gis data (fault lines) for different states and created a new tool to iterate through those.  i then brought in the "path iterator" hoping to combine them so it would show the intersect of Path A and all the fault lines by state, then iterate through Path B and all the fault lines by state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the second iterator in a separate model in ModelBuilder.  Once you've got that working you can insert it as a submodel into Iterator 1.  ModelBuilder won't ordinarily let you nest iterators, but it *will* let you include a submodel.  If that submodel has an iterator in it you can get around the "1 iterator only" limit.

Comment: thanks!  that's what i thought.  apparently the submodel isn't working correctly then.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible to use more than one iterator in a ModelBuilder model. (Ref. [A quick tour of using iterators for iteration](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002w0000001w000000), the first "Note" towards the end.)

There are some ideas for getting around this limitation in Answers to this Question: [Nesting two iterators for cost distance calculation in ModelBuilder?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15012/issue-nesting-two-iterators-for-cost-distance-calculation-model-builder)